# Why is SelectLayerByAttribute_management claiming "Column Does Not Exist"?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute, error-000358

The [solution to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222363/a-column-was-specified-that-does-not-exist-error-when-running-select-layer-by) is not working for me.

My error message:

> File "SumAreas.py", line 24, in 
>   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION, '"CLASS_CODE" = "A"')
>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6688, in
>   SelectLayerByAttribute raise e
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 000358:
>   Invalid expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Further message in Python Window's side window:

```
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
A column was specified that does not exist.
```

I am trying to select based on a column ("CLASS_CODE") which is of "String" type.

My line 24 (referenced in Error Message above):

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", '"CLASS_CODE" = "A"')
```

I can confirm that feature class "fc" definitely has a column called "CLASS_CODE".

So if the column exists, and is spelled correctly, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the value `"A"` that is seen as a column. To use the string value, you would need to use and [escape](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) single quotes.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", '"CLASS_CODE" = \'A\'')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on
>   the format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

And three quotes:

```
sql = """{0} = 'A'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, 'CLASS_CODE')
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", sql)
```